# Where does Samba 4 store user passwords?

Tags: login, samba, password, authentication, ldap

Where does Samba 4 store user passwords? How can I import my password hashes from Samba 3 in Samba 4?

I am using my own LDAP server with samba 3, and the password hash is stored within the `userpassword` attribute of the user entry (passdb backend: ldapsam).

However Samba 4 uses it own LDAP server and shema, and it does not seem to work when I copy this attribute in the Samba 4 user entry.

How can I store Samba 4 passwords within an LDAP attribute?

Answer (score 3):

> Where does Samba 4 store user passwords?

In it's own (integrated) LDAP-server in the attribute `unicodePwd`. This attribute is not available through LDAP (e.g. `ldapsearch` does not show it). But you can use for example `ldbsearch` to view the attribute.

> How can I import my password hashes from Samba 3 in Samba 4?

You should use Samba Classic Upgrade, see [the samba wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_Classic_Upgrade_%28NT4-style_domain_to_AD%29) for more information.

> How can I store Samba 4 passwords within an LDAP attribute?

You should not modify the LDAP attribute directly. You can use `samba-tool user setpassword` to set a new password for a user. For the migration you should really use classic upgrade which works well with the Samba 3 LDAP backend.

Answer (score 2):

When I setup a Samba server, the passwords get store in /etc/shadow.